# Converting to Spherical Coordinates that have a Large Azimuth?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, vectors, spherical-coordinates

I've run into a problem converting Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates. Say I've got a vector/point $p=(-1,5,7\frac{2}{3})$. Obviously, finding the polar angle/inclination isn't going to pose much of a problem, as it's defined through an arccosine, which means that its output is going to be between $0$ and $\pi$, perfectly matching any possible inclination you can get along the z-axis.

However, [if you plot the vector/point](http://www.bodurov.com/VectorVisualizer/?vectors=0/0/0/-1/5/7.66666667), you'll see that the ***azimuthal angle*** is far bigger: almost 360 degrees from the looks of it. Why is this a problem? Because, when converting from Cartesian to Spherical coordinates, one uses:

$$\text{Azimuthal Angle}=\arctan{\frac{y}{x}}$$
and since an arctangent's output exists only as: $\frac{-\pi}{2}<output<\frac{\pi}{2}$, I run into the problem of being unable to find the correct azimuthal angle for this particular point, or any point with an azimuth $>\frac{\pi}{2}$ for that matter.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because $\frac{-y}{-x} = \frac yx.$ This causes the
arc tangent to give the same result for $(-x,-y)$ as for $(x,y).$

One way to address the problem is to take $\pi + \tan \frac yx$ as the azimuthal angle
whenever $x$ is negative, and then add or subtract $2\pi$ if needed in order to 
put the result in the range of angle values you desire.
(This measures the azimuthal angle counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis.)

In many types of mathematical software and computer programming languages,
a two-parameter function (typically called ${\tt atan2}$) is provided that produces a
value in the range $[-\pi,\pi]$ so that ${\tt atan2}(y,x)$
is the azimuthal angle of $(x,y).$
If you prefer your angles to be in the range $[0,2\pi]$ then you would need to
add $2\pi$ to the result of the function when that result is negative.